# Проблема с regex в nginx конфиге

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx, phpmyadmin, proxy

Хочу сделать reverse proxy на phpmyadmin, для этого пишу в location регулярное выражение, чтобы он искал по папке и внутри нее файлы .php, но ничего не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
    location /(phpmyadmin|*.php$) {
    # rewrite ^\/phpmyadmin\/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://$host:5000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    # proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: `location ~ /(phpmyadmin)/.*\.(php)$`

Comment: [Не надо ставить PhpMyAdmin, вообще](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin).